# PHP CURL creating and using uniquely named cookie files

Tags: php, curl

I have a php script that is being used login into a remote site and it is working well. However it seems to only works when the designated cookie file is named `cookie.txt`

What I want is for each person who uses this script to have a separate cookie file. So if a person on machineA uses it on the 19th they're cookie will be located in something like `/tmp/19/someNameCookie.txt`, machineB would have `/tmp/19/someOtherNamedCookie.txt`, and if machineC uses it on the 20th they will have `/tmp/20/someNamedCookie.txt`.

There are many ways to generate uniquely named files but the key here is getting them to work. I've very young in the php knowledge and completely new to curl.

On a side note, I've also have had no success using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` for getting the new page that results from logging in.

Thanks.

---

Here's a code exert. Got to this from another source.

```
$username=urlencode($usr); 
$password=urlencode($pass); 
$url="http://domain.com/"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); // have tried with just the jar, and just the file and both 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

And this is the code I would call after to check if the login is successful

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.com/");

$r = curl_exec($ch2);
echo $r;
curl_close($ch2);
```

From my understanding curl is supposed to create the cookie file if it doesn't exist. I've also tried creating other files manually and through script using fopen but still only works if I'm using cookie.txt, and right now it's all being saved to public_html just for testing.

Comment: Can we see some code? Specifically where it's saving to `cookie.txt`

Comment: Read this ---> http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php#90821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the `Cookie Jar`

```
<?php
    $machine = 'PC_A'; // here it's your problem how you define each machine
    $cookie_file = "/tmp/".date('d')."/".$machine."_cookie.txt";
    // and set the cURL cookie jar and file

    if (!file_exists($cookie_file) || !is_writable($cookie_file)){
            echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
            die;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
?>
```

Comment: I was doing something similar but still didn't save the cookie nor did it login. Even tried making sure that the tmp folder existed in the root directory, and have tried the absolute directory.

Comment: are you sure your script has permissions to write in `/tmp` ?

Comment: no :P
I'm using cyberduck to connect to my server, the permissions it gives is 744. Do I need to set permissions from my webhost?

Comment: Okay, it gives me the error message you created. So does that mean it doesn't have the proper permissions then?

Comment: check if writable ... the code I've posted, if it's not .. than yes .. create a folder with permissions and put cookies there.

Comment: Thanks that helps, now I know what the problem is. So should the folder's permissions be 755 and the file 755?

Comment: the file will be created by the cURL if it has permissions, so don't worry about that, worry about the folder

Answer (score 0):

use for example session_id() for cookie file name, it is unique for every single machine connecting to your application, and its still the same till it expires